# Applying case class to indidual field in a nested form Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to apply a case class to an individual field inside of a Scala Play form. the field I am trying it apply it to is `exerciseName` inside of the `setsForm` variable.

```
  case class ExerciseName(exerciseName:String)
  case class WorkoutSet(exerciseName:ExerciseName, number:Int)
  case class WorkoutSets(sets:List[WorkoutSet]) 
  val setsForm:Form[WorkoutSets] = Form( 
    mapping( 
      "workoutSets" -> list(mapping
      (   
        //i need to get exerciseName to be of type ExerciseName somehow...
        "exerciseName" ->nonEmptyText,  
        "workoutSet" -> number(min=1,max=20)
        )(WorkoutSet.apply)(WorkoutSet.unapply))
    )(WorkoutSets.apply)(WorkoutSets.unapply)
  )
```

I was wondering if anyone could provide me any insight on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val setsForm:Form[WorkoutSets] = Form(
    mapping(
      "sets" -> list(
        mapping(
          "exerciseName" -> mapping("exerciseName" -> nonEmptyText)(ExerciseName.apply)    (ExerciseName.unapply),
          "workoutSet" -> number(min=1,max=20)
        )(WorkoutSet.apply)(WorkoutSet.unapply)
      )
    )(WorkoutSets.apply)(WorkoutSets.unapply)
)
```

I'd also recommend changing the field name of ExerciseName to "name" to avoid confusion.